# Unable to add CordovaLib as a target dependency

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I'm trying to the the phoneGap framework as a library, there is something called CordovaLib which suppose to support it. here are the instractions http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html

I followed the steps completely, however on step 23 I can't find the CordovaLib to add, and if I skip it I can't import the CDVViewController.

It looks like a basic Xcode configuration issue, Can anyone help me with that?

[Update] i've installed 1.9.0 and it works fine. they did some changes in the way they link the Lib in 2.0.0 and change the instructions accordingly however it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble with adding the target dependency as well.

One possible workaround is to open the CordovaLib project and build.  This will create the CordovaLib.a library that you need to replace the pre 2.0 framework.  You can then copy that library into your project and add it as a library dependency in the build phase area.

Comment: i've tried this with no success, I have the cordovalib.a but still I cant as a dependency, and worse, the compiler can't find the .h files so its not compiling...